# Plot a function defined on terms on its value on an interval

Tags: plotting, functions

Besicovitch-Ursell family of fractal functions uses the following auxiliary definition:

$\phi(x) = 2x$ on $[0,1/2]$.

$\phi(-x) = \phi(x+1)$ otherwise.

Is there a way to plot this in Mathematica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
\[Phi][x_] :=Which[0 <= x <= 1/2, 2 x, x < 0, \[Phi][1 + x], True, \[Phi][1 -x]]
Plot[\[Phi][x], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

is what you are looking for?

Comment: Or use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html).

Answer (score 3):

[image: Knopp function plot]

Also called Knopp function in Edgar's other book:

```
f[x_] := 2*x /; 0 <= x <= 1/2
f[x_] := 2 - 2*x /; 1/2 < x <= 1

ff[x_] = f[Mod[Abs[x], 1]];
Plot[f[Mod[Abs[x], 1]], {x, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: Hi Roger, glad to see you posting here!

Comment: `f[x_] = Piecewise[{{2 x, 0 <= x <= 1/2}, {2 - 2 x, 1/2 < x <= 1}}];
Plot[f[Mod[x, 1]], {x, -2, 2}]`

Comment: I have a data base of Besicovitch-Ursell-Knopp functions in 1d,2d, and 3d and even some Steriographic 4d / Clifford projections dating back to right after I bought Edgar's fractal geometry which I mostly translated into Mathematica. This function form that I posted is "robust" and seldom fails. The Sierpinski gasket fractal form using a unitary cantor cartoon is maybe the most classic. It should be mentioned that the Mandelbrot cartoon functions in his papers on stock markets are these sorts of functions as well.

Comment: Here is a very recent updated example: 8step Minkowski Sausage updated color:
My post here updated for color:
https://groups.google.com/g/sci.fractals/c/1Bj0oXRKtiY
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/roger.bagula/Published/8step_Minkowski%20_Sausage%20_xydualcartoon3d3scale_updated_color.nb